# HTML5 Video Scaling

Tags: css, html, video, html5-video

i want a HTML5 video element to fill the frame of the containing DIV. I use the following CSS, which works fine in Safari:

```
video {
    position:absolute;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: cover; 
}
```

But when opened in IE 11, there is a black frame around the video, depending on the browser window size. Is there another way to make IE behave like Safari?

Best Regards
Jörg

Answer (score 0):

object-fit CSS property is not supported by Internet Explorer.
Maybe you'd better try a polyfill if you **really** want to have this behavior ( https://github.com/anselmh/object-fit )